# Tesseract crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tesseract

I am using tesseract on my iOS device and it was working properly until recently it started to crash on me. I have been testing with the same image over and over again and prior to now I had it working about 75 times consecutively. The only thing I can think of is that I deleted the app from my iOS device and then ran it again through Xcode.

I am far from an expert on tesseract and I could really use some advice on what to do next, it would truly be a disappointment for all the hours I put in to go to waste because I cannot read the image anymore. Thank you

This is the crash error it appears to happen when the tesseract file in this method

```
- (BOOL)recognize {
int returnCode = _tesseract->Recognize(NULL); // here is where the arrow points on the crash
return (returnCode == 0) ? YES : NO;
 }
```

This is the snapshot of the crash

[image]